# sed delete patterned lines but ignore commented lines with the same pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have lines in my config file :

```
#-A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
#-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 -j DROP 
#-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i  br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Lines that are having 'physdev' string are of my interest and want to apply a (sed)rule on this file such that rule has to ignore comment lines having 'physdev' string and delete the uncommented lines having 'physdev' string. Could you please suggest an sed delete pattern or any awk pattern.

Comment: Please add your attempts and explain where you find difficulty in.

Comment: And include the actual expected output given that input. And try to rephrase your requirements - you're making it sound far more complicated than necessary with all the [double] negatives. Focus on simply stating what you want to **print** (positive), not what you want to delete (negative) and the result will be something extremely simple like `I want to print the lines that neither start with # nor contain physdev` (if that is what you're trying to say, right now the question is very ambiguous).

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
#-A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
#-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 -j DROP 
#-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i  br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You can do:

```
$ awk '$1~/^#/{print; next} /physdev/{next} 1' file
#-A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
#-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 -j DROP 
#-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in eth2 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i  br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution .. it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you want to delete all uncommented lines containig physdev (that's what you want, right?), sed is at least as elegant as awk:

```
sed -e '/^[^#].*physdev/d' file
```

If you want the changes to be written in the file, use `sed -i -e ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution .. it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e '/^#/n;/physdev/d' file`

`/^#/n` just advances to the next line of the input whever a line begins with `#`

This has the effect of ignoring ALL subsequent sed commands when `/^#/` matches.  So if you know you always want to retain all lines beginning with `#`, making `/^#/n` the first command will do so, regardless of how many or how complex the subsequent commands get.